# Is there a one-liner to get specific parts of this string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm having a string like "a.b.c.d.e".

If I want to get an array like "a.b.c.d.e", "b.c.d.e", "c.d.e", "d.e", "e" in C#. What's the simplest approach?

Comment: Why a one-liner? Once you've got some working code you can try to decrease its size, usually Linq is especially useful there. Please show your code.

Comment: My current code is just using String.Split('.') and then followed by a loop. I'm interested to know if there's any simple approach.

Comment: @Forrest That sounds like a sufficient approach. To make it "one line", but the code into a method and call it.

Comment: Simplest doesn't always mean shortest.  The best solution is the one that you can understand and maintain for the life of the project.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this will do:

```
var stringParts = input.Split('.');
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, stringParts.Length)
                       .Select(i => string.Join(".", stringParts.Skip(i)));
```

But like I said in my comment, please show the code you came up with and **why** you want to make it a one-liner, which usually doesn't serve any benefit. This isn't codegolf.

Comment: `input.Split(".")` won't compile.change it to char :)

Comment: @Selman thanks, it's hard to remember all overloads. I think I commonly use an extension method that does allow for a single string argument.

Comment: the life would be easier if there is an overload of `Split` that takes a `params string[]` :)

Answer (score 4):

If you really do it with one statement,  you can try this:

```
var str = "a.b.c.d.e";
var parts = str.Split('.')
            .Select((x,idx) => new { idx })
            .Select(p => string.Join(".",
                        str.Split('.').Skip(p.idx))).ToList();
```

This could be more efficient if you use `Split` first:

```
var parts = str.Split('.');
var result = parts
            .Select((x,idx) => new { idx })
            .Select(p => string.Join(".",
                        parts.Skip(p.idx))).ToList();
```

You can also do it without creating anonymous type(s), just create an int variable:

```
int i = 0;
var result = parts
           .Select(p => string.Join(".", parts.Skip(i++)))
           .ToList();
```

Comment: I can't believe this got an upvote the second it was posted (and not out of jealousy my answer didn't ;-). This code _splits the input string N+2 times_ (where N is the amount of dots in the input string) and instantiates a new collection of integers stored in an anonymous type, only for the sake of making it a one-statement piece of code which frankly isn't more readable than a simple for loop.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I think the question is ill-conceived.  I up-voted simply because it answered the question ;)

Comment: @CodeCaster I didn't say it's the best way of doing it and didn't recommend it.also I have added another approach which exactly solves that problem.

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer, it is fine and does indeed answer the question. :) - @mellamokb that is why I asked OP **why**. :)

Comment: How 'bout creating `List<List<string>>` with `let` Linq clause, and then somehow adding each string to each existing list, plus one new empty list? Don't know how to do that though...

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly neat:

```
var text = "a.b.c.d.e";

var results =
    text
        .Split('.')
        .Reverse()
        .Scan("", (a, x) => x + "." + a)
        .Select(x => x.TrimEnd('.'))
        .Reverse();
```

You do need to add the Microsoft Reactive Extensions Team's "Interactive Extensions" to get the `Scan` operator. Use NuGet and look for "Ix-Main".

Comment: Please define "fairly neat". You'll have to download a third-party library to use this code and it is very unintuitive to see what is going on here.

Comment: @CodeCaster not really true, `Scan` if you're using RX already (which a lot of projects are) Scan should be very obvious

Comment: @George I'm not solely talking about the `Scan()` call, but about reading this code in three months and interpreting what it does again.

Comment: You have it in its own component or a well named private method of course

Comment: @George it's not about where you place this code, but what happens in your head when you read it, which is a part of its maintainability as pointed out by [@mellamokb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648544/is-there-a-one-liner-to-get-specific-parts-of-this-string/22648774#comment34496139_22648544).

Comment: That's subjective though, if I came from an exclusively functional reactive programming background then this answer would feel far more obvious and maintainable than one featuring loops. You could argue that your answer (which to be honest I find quite clean) is more idiomatic but C# is incing closer and closer to F#, its serving many masters nowadays. My point is that the specifics of how maintainable an algorithm like this is are subjective, what is far more important is that it be called something like `splitIterativelyAndBuildUpArray` and have a test or at least a documented sample usage

Comment: @CodeCaster - "Fairly neat" must be an Australian idiom. It just means that I was happy with the solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Also, as far as intuition goes, I find my kind of answer more intuitive. You can read it from the top, one lin at a time, an not need to go back up to work out what's going on. In an iterative approach using a loop you need to almost compile the code in your head. It's actually harder to understand loops with state, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I actually kind of like this question, not necessarily production but a bit of brain-bendy fun:

```
"a.b.c.d.e".Split('.').Reverse()
    .Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), (acc, c) => 
        acc.Concat(new [] { c+(acc.LastOrDefault()??"") })
    ).Reverse()
```

[Dotnetfiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/tTHnb5)

What this does is move through each character in the split array and build up a new array by prepending the last value in the array with the current character. It's a fairly common functional programming technique.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I might write it.. I know, not "one line", but if you're gonna use (and I do recommend) a method anyway..

```
IEnumerable<string> AllComponentPartsForward (string s) {
    IEnumerable<string> p = s.Split('.');
    while (p.Any()) {
       yield return string.Join(".", p); // p.ToArray() for .NET 3.5
       p = p.Skip(1);
    }
}
```

(I suppose it could be "more efficient" with IndexOf/Substring, but that's also harder for me to write and reason about!)